# Can I use Caliburn Framework in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, caliburn

Can I use Caliburn Framework in Windows.Forms application? or it use only in wpf applications?

Comment: WPF applications are windows applications. Do you mean WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use it with WPF and Silverlight applications. That's not to say that you couldn't take the concepts in Caliburn and apply them to WinForms. But out of the box, Caliburn requires WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: WPF and Silverlight's support for data-binding is richer than Windows Forms, so that might be a little problematic for implementing the MVVM pattern on top of WinForms but should still be possible.

Comment: MVVM using WinForms is possible - I've done it - it's not as easy or straightforward as WPF. Worth the effort, though.

Comment: This is kind of related [MVVM for winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982978/mvvm-for-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of Caliburn.Micro for Windows Forms and Visual WebGUI. The initial port was a fork made by Dan Durland. Now it's a separate project that I'm cordinating. I won't name it, as the last time I did, I got into a lot of trouble.