# Datagrid view to fill based on columns

Tags: c#

Below is my Datagridview code to get the data from employee table.

the problem am facing is ,my employee table have 10 columns (ID,emplNo,Dob,JoingData...etc)

i just want to fill my grid with only ID,EmplyNo and DOB.

but the below code get everything,please advise me what i suppose to do to get only particular column

```
          string sql = "select * from Employee";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
        //SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
          dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
       // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, scrollVal, 5, "Employee");
        connection.Close();
        dgMessages.DataSource = ds;
        dgMessages.DataMember = "tEmployee";
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
   string sql = "select * from Employee";
```

do

```
   string sql = "select ID, EmplyNo, DOB from Employee";
```

Answer (score 1):

either change your select to only get the supset of what you want or use the designer:
[image]
[image]

it's a bit of a pain because you first have to add an unbound column and then edit the just added column to setthe DataPropertyName to a column-name in your resulting table - but it works.

You find this dialogs by clicking the "..." in the "columns" property of the PropertyEditor for the DataGridView or by clicking the little "Play"-Button on the top-right of the Grid in the designer (when it is selected)

Almost forgot: IMPORTANT: you need to add EVERY column and set Visible=False on those you don't want to see - I think this is different in WebForms where there is something like AutogenerateColumns.

Comment: I think you missed something, because although you design 3 columns, in the runtime, if the `DataSource` having 4 or more columns, it will display all, unless you handle it with `grid.Columns[name].Visible = false`

Comment: well read the last 2 lines ... have to admit I forgot it in the first go but I added those lines a short time after. I don't use WinForms anymore nor do I WebForms so I tend to forget where the AutoGenerate-bla stuff was.

Comment: thanks CKoenig, actuall i added the column and one of my column is hyperlink,now the problem is how to add the value to the coulum.

Comment: you see the "DataPropertyName" in the "Data"-Section of the property-editor above? There you have to put the name of your column in the DataTable - in your case "EmplyNo" for example (without the "" of course) BTW: you don't have to use a dataset if you only need the DataTable! This way you might have to say "tEmployee.EmplyNo" but I don't think so)

Comment: i was trying to do something like below datagridview.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = EmpId something like that but am not sure how to do.

Comment: have a look at that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092391/c-winform-datagridview-inline-add-new-row/7092426#7092426 it's almost the same. If not please ask again - this is seperate from your question above

Comment: this was the actual code i was doing to pull the message from my Q and load it in to my datagridview column,now i am planning to do the same for sql table. you mentioned i have to use datatable but i couldn't find any examples but found only dataset.here is my code

Comment: ErrGrid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = "123XXX";
ErrGrid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Here am trying to load my employee no from sql table";
ErrGrid.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = "MessageType";
ErrGrid.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = "Sender";
ErrGrid.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = msgInfo[msgInfo.Length - 1];
ErrGrid.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = m.ToString();