Winforms and Dependency injections
I am working on Winforms and Dependency Injection. Question 8 and 9 is quite confusing. Please help.
Create a windows forms application to manage XXX data.  The application must:

Have at least 5 properties for the model class
Use binding technique
Use the MVVM pattern
Have data saved to and loaded from a file
Use asynchronous file reading / writing
Have a separate form to display the detail information
Have the data sorted by two properties when displaying in the grid view
Make view and view model classes loosely-coupled so that they can be implemented parallelly and view model can be replaced when used with view
Use dependency injection to automatically creating view and view model object​

I need to understand this whole concept of DI. It's a bit confusing to understand

All these concepts are usually used with WPF.  Is this for a class or something that you are studying on your own?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982978/mvvm-for-winforms and https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2023/using-mvvm-design-pattern-in-windows-forms

If you look into requirement number 3 and find a working example of the pattern, it will go a long way to explaining 8 and 9.
In its simplest form, you're looking at abstracting your view to an interface and then 'injecting' an implementation of it into the view model, usually via its constructor. This way the view model and view are loosely coupled, as the view model only depends on an abstraction, not a concrete type.
In terms of DI and IoC, you can wire-up the components using 'Pure DI' or by leaning on an IoC container. Have a look at one of my other answers that explains it in a bit more detail.
