# Presentation Design Patterns

Tags: .net, winforms, design-patterns, presentation-layer

I've been studying and working with presentation design patterns for a while, and i have successfully impleneted design patterns like `FrontController`, `MVP` etc. for `WebApps`, and of course the `MVC` pattern and the `ASP.NET MVC` framework which is a great choice. however, i was wondering if using a presentation pattern like `MVP` would be a good choice for `WinForms` applications. if the answer is yes then great, if not and/or there are pitfalls to be aware of it would be great if you could explain the ideas a little bit about different presentation patterns in `WinForms` applications.

Comment: Fowler has retired MVP and split it into **Supervising Controller** and **Passive View**: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595469/ui-design-pattern-for-windows-forms-like-mvvm-for-wpf

Comment: You might want to add a more specific question at the bottom: `What presentation patterns are available for WinForms applications, and what are there pros/cons?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All presentation patterns derive from MVC. However, Model2 is what ASP.NET MVC gives us, MVP is devided in Passive View (PV) and Supervising Controller (SC) and Presentation Model is what the MVVM give us.

For the Web,

- Model 2
- MVP (both PV and SC)

For the Windows Forms

- MVP (both PV and SC)

For the WPF

- MVP (both PV, SC)
- MVVM

There is a very nice figure from the book "Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise" which presents MVC, MVP, MVVM and what can be fit in Windows Forms, Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC.

The figure 7-14 is on page 374, however you can also watch it [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B8-HfnKExilBMjM5ODRhYWUtZmQzZi00OTY0LThiMjktODZlODQwZGU4Y2E1&hl=en_US).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look the following [article](http://blog.ashraful.net/archive/2012/02/19/design-patterns-for-model.aspx) where few popular and new design patterns that are related to presentation component and model are described.