# .net winforms template projects

Tags: .net, winforms, templates

I'm building a simple winforms application that will have a modal login dialogue and needs basic tooling for things like logging etc.

Are there any known sources for a sample project thats already setup following recommended patterns?

Obviously I can start from scratch, but if there were some best practice .net winforms 4 sample application projects from Microsoft or from an open source project that would help jumpstart things following good design patterns

Answer (score 0):

The [Build Your Own CAB Series by Jeremy Miller](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents/) is a good place to start. See also [UI Design Pattern for Windows Forms (like MVVM for WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595469/ui-design-pattern-for-windows-forms-like-mvvm-for-wpf) and [Implementing MVC with Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654722/implementing-mvc-with-windows-forms/)