# WinForms 2010 DataBinding and DB Access

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm a Silverlight developer that has to work on a WinForms project again, but I'm not too excited to leave the wonderful world of data binding behind. In the past I always used DataSets with SQL queries. Are there any good tutorials to update my skills?

Some comments on what I want:

- Regarding Entity Framework, it seems nice, but the last time I checked it did not handle custom situations very well. Is there perhaps a more hybrid customised solution where I have more control in my hands? For example, a custom data source with custom actions on save.
- I don't want to use raw text in binding lookups, and already found a useful article for [Safe WinForms Databinding in C# 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/SafeDataBinding.aspx), but there are probably better standards in .NET 4.

**Sample Form**

[ Employee Selection (Dropdown - to populate fields below, query DB on change) ]

[ Employee Detail (individual fields - fairly generic) ]

[ Grid (or list) with CheckBoxes for linked responsibilities (not so generic) ]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Silverlight developer, but as far as I know, there is *not a big difference in dataBindings in Silverlight and WinForms* applications.

As for ORMs (if you don't like Entity framework), you could try **LINQ to SQL**. The great blog tutorial is [here](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/07/27/links-to-scott-guthrie-s-using-linq-to-sql-tutorials.aspx). But *Microsoft recommends to use EF instead of LINQ to SQL* in new applications. Also [**NHibernate**](http://www.codecovered.net/2011/04/nhibernate-tutorial-part-1-introduction.html) is a good alternative.

As for exactly **DataBindings in WinForms**, check [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/databinding_tutorial.aspx). THen you'll be able to compare that to what you know from Silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight works great with the MVVM pattern, which is what I'll use for comparison. I'm a bit busy with other things right now, but I will look at your links and get back to you.

Comment: You can use MVVM in WPF and there are MVVM patterns for WinForms as well. Here some links:           
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfMvvmQuickStart.aspx             
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfMvvmQuickStart.aspx              
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595469/ui-design-pattern-for-windows-forms-like-mvvm-for-wpf                 
Hope that will help...