# Binding UI Elements With Entities

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application and what i want to achieve is making the Userinterface auto updates it self once the objects it is binded to is changed.

This is the what i have tried but unfortunately the text box text isn't changed automatically!

```
Employee employee = new Employee();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", employee, "Name");
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employee.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Comment: It seems you're looking for a MVVM framework for WinForms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595469/ui-design-pattern-for-windows-forms-like-mvvm-for-wpf

Comment: Sounds like you aren't deep enough into working with WinForm that it would make a difference for you to switch to WPF. Seriously. WinForm is a seriously flawed tech.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the employee name in `button1_Click`, you could update `textBox1`' Text property by calling the `ReadValue` method to enforce `textBox1` re-read the binding value.

```
textBox1.DataBindings[0].ReadValue();
```

Or, You could warp the depending employee instance into a `BindingSource`, and reset BindingSource in `button1_Click`.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
BindingSource source;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = employee;

    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", source, "Name");
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employee.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    source.ResetCurrentItem();
}
```